# How can I get the url of a page that didn't load with javascript?

Tags: javascript, url, firefox-addon

I am trying to code an add-on for Firefox that redirects you to another website if the URL includes any given string. This works for pages that load correctly, but say if a page didnt load(could be blocked etc.) my code doesn't get the URL.

I tried `window.location.href` but this does not work on unloaded pages.

For pages that load, `window.location.href` works.
I expect to get the URL even on pages that failed to load.

Long story short, I want to know how can I get the URL of this page with javascript? 
http://www.randomrandomrandomrandom.com/

Comment: You appear to be looking at this from the wrong point of view. You should be performing this operation in your background script, not a content script. For what you've described, you shouldn't be using a content script at all. You should look into the events available from `webNavigation`, `tabs`, and `webRequest`.

Answer (score 0):

I think you might want to look into the [tabs.getCurrent](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Add-ons/WebExtensions/API/tabs/getCurrent) function from the Mozilla docs. As you said, `window.location.href` only works once the page is loaded, so what you want to do is check for the URL before the page is even loaded since you are not sure whether it will load or not.

```
function getURL(tabInfo) {
   console.log(tabInfo.url);
}

function logError(error) {
    console.log(`Error: ${error}`);
}

var gettingCurrent = browser.tabs.getCurrent();
gettingCurrent.then(getURL, logError);
```

The URL option is only present if the extension has the "tabs" permission. ([Source](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Add-ons/WebExtensions/API/tabs/Tab))

Comment: Thank you, but even with proper manifest.json permissions, copying your code and to my add-on and executing it gave me no results.